# How can I fix the IndexError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this program (It is supposed to encode and decode things in and out of the Caesar cipher) and opt for the decode option, I get the error saying that the string index is out of range. Can anyone tell me how to fix this and tell me why it is happening? The text I entered for it to decode was ibmmp and the key was 1.Thanks.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
encdec = input("Would you like to encode or decode a message? ")
if encdec == "decode":
    keyyn = input("Do you know the key to your encoded text? (Y/N) ")
    if keyyn == "Y":
        plaintext = input("Please type in your text ")
        text = plaintext
        key = int(input("What is the key? "))
        for i in range(len(plaintext)):
            letter = plaintext[i]
            alphletter = alphabet.find(letter)
            alphletter = alphletter - key
            if alphletter < 0 or alphletter == 0:
                alphletter = alphletter + 26
                letter = alphabet[alphletter]
                plaintext = plaintext + letter
    else:
        letter = alphabet[alphletter]
        plaintext = plaintext + letter
    print(plaintext.strip(text))
else:
    print("This program is unable to decode a message without the key")
```

Comment: Would it be at all possible to give an example that causes this problem?

Comment: You need to show the full traceback. There's lots of places it could be happening, the traceback will tell us which.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
It's not acceptable to dump the entire program on us with required input and no debugging attempt.

Comment: `plaintext = input("Please type in your text ")` and `keyyn = input("Do` aren't indented under your `if` statements

Comment: Looks like there are some indentation issues, especially with `if` statements. Fixing those and any others would help us.

Comment: Sorry about the indentation issues, it is my first time on this site and I didn't realise that the indentations don't copy across. It should be fixed now.

Comment: You should look at the module (`%`) operator .. it fixes over/underflow:   `(24+9)%26` == `7`  - so if you got the 24. character and a key of 9 this fixes your lookup index for nothing - further optimizations: store the alphabet in a dict as `char-->index` and `index-->char` then use the dict for lookup instead of `index()` - it is _much_ faster

Answer (score 1):

Problem:   `ibmmp` and key of 1

`i` works, `b` gives you an error. Here is why:

> ```
> alphletter = alphabet.find(letter)              #  ==> 1
> alphletter = alphletter - key                   #  ==> 0
> if alphletter < 0 or alphletter == 0:           #  ==> True
>     alphletter = alphletter + 26                    #   ==> 26 
> letter = alphabet[alphletter]                   #  only has indexes from 0 to 25
> plaintext = plaintext + letter                  #   ~~~~ crash ~~~~
> # (also: indentation error for the last 2 lines)
> ```

You can use the modulo-operator `%` to fix over/underflow:

```
alphletter = (alphletter - key) % 26   # for -1 : 25
```

You could also use `if alphletter < 0:` - this will not handle keys thats wrap around multiple times (f.e. `210`) or negative keys `-22`

---

Some optimizations

```
# create a mapping dictionary so we do not need index()
alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
len_alph = len(alph)

d = {c:i for i,c in enumerate(alph)}                  # mapping char to index
d.update( {v:k for k,v in d.items()} )                # mapping index to char
d.update( {c:i for i,c in enumerate(alph.upper())} )  # mapping CHAR to index

def encode(text,key):
    indexes = [d.get(c,"?") for c in text]      # only mapped things, others get ?
    # if ? use ? else lookup the correct replacement using % to make the index
    # wrap around if above/below the index into alph 
    return ''.join(d.get((i+key)%len_alph if i != "?" else "?","?") for i in indexes)

def decode(text,key):
    return encode(text,-key)


print(encode("tataaaa",5))
```

Output:

```
yfyffff
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The program now works. I would use the optimizations however, this was part of the topic we are currently studying which is string manipulation and so I have to do it this way as we have not learnt everything mentioned in that optimized script.

Comment: @WMurphy You'll come there eventually :) glad it helped.